# How to create JS object literal and pass into JS method in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I **have a button in the XSLT template**, this button onclick event link with the javascript method which is called clickMe.

The clickMe method accepts the JS object as an argument because I would like to apply the same click event in different controls and passing different properties of the object.

For example:

```
<button type="button" title="Click A" onclick="clickMe({ firstName: "Y" });" />
<button type="button" title="Click B" onclick="clickMe({ helloWorld: "123" });" />
<button type="button" title="Click C" onclick="clickMe({ isCorrect: "true" });" />
```

How to dynamically generate the object literal string in XSLT? and pass into javascript method as above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent curly braces from being interpreted as attribute values templates by the XSLT processor you need to double them: `onclick="clickMe({{ firstName: 'Y' }});"`.

Comment: Thanks Martin! stay safe!